# Space between sentences missing from bounty grace period notice

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, spelling, post-notices

The grace period notice for bounties is like this (for example):

> ### This question had a bounty worth +50 reputation from gparyani that ended 23 hours ago.You have 10 minutes to award the bounty
>
> The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given
>   recent changes.
>
> http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/202606/can-we-automatically-detect-discouraged-patterns-in-question-titles

If you look at the Markdown or press <kbd>F7</kbd>, you can see that there is no space between "ago." and "You". When will this typo be corrected?

Comment: And here I thought it was just bad keming.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I thought so too, until I pressed F7 and discovered this bug.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I think you mistyped. You typed "`m`" instead of "`rn`" in "`kerning`". F7 told me that too...

Comment: @gparyani He's mocking the bad kerning that makes `rn` look like `m`.

Comment: There was no bug; you had an invisible character in your markdown (don't know why...) anyway, edited. @Bolt lol, you tricked me there :D I didn't even notice until I read the comrnents :P

Comment: @Doorknob The F7 key is very useful, isn't it? I didn't find it until I looked at the revision history and scrolled through it using the caret cursor...

Comment: @gparyani F7? Don't you mean F12?

Comment: @Doorknob F7 enables Caret Browsing in Internet Explorer, which puts a movable cursor through the page as though it is a document. I can then use the arrow keys to find invisible characters as well as this problem.

Comment: @Downvoter Could you explain your rationale?

Comment: @Doorknob You mistyped too...you inputted `comrnents`...

Comment: Also visible to other users: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pvp6c.png (Was going to report this myself, but found this existing report.)

Comment: Should it be one space or two? http://xkcd.com/1285/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be out in the next build.