# Could we have a space between these words please?

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties

Maybe it's me; I've just got done proofreading a written paper where there was a lack of spaces.  But now, when I see it, it kind of...**screams** at me.

[image]

I *really* think that a space belongs after that period.

Comment: Hmm, this was [supposedly already fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203601/space-between-sentences-missing-from-bounty-grace-period-notice)...

Comment: Bad build, then?

Comment: Seen here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203777/for-search-effectiveness-shouldnt-so-tags-be-as-generic-as-possible

Comment: @TimStone: A duplicate then... I guess mods should remove the [meta-tag:status-completed] tag from the source until its fixed.

Comment: I would upvote this, but the oval isn't freehand.

Comment: I would have had it freehand.  Blame Mac OS X.

Comment: What is the build number at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Even if it's a dupe, we prefer new bug reports rather than un-status-completing old ones, so this question is fine as it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can have that extra whitespace.It's rolled out with the 2013.11.13.* build revs.

Comment: GAH!  You did it too!  Well, thanks for getting a fix out for it, anyway.